# Oracle SQL CASE WHEN IS NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am learning Oracle SQL :)

1.

> ```
> CASE s.COURSE_SCHEDULED_ID
>     WHEN IS NULL THEN 'false'
>     ELSE 'true'
> END AS "Is scheduled?"
> ```

2. 

> ```
> CASE 
>     WHEN s.COURSE_SCHEDULED_ID IS NULL THEN 'false'
>     ELSE 'true'
> END AS "Is scheduled?"
> ```

Why 1 is not working?

Comment: Mark the choice **3** :) `NVL2(s.course_scheduled_id,'true','false') AS "Is scheduled?"` is the best for the current case.

Comment: You can't use `when is null` for the same reason you can't use `when = 2`. The `when` keyword needs to be followed by a literal.

Comment: When we're at it, note that there's also DECODE you might want to consider: `decode(course_scheduled_id, null, 'false', 'true')`. It is usually suggested that CASE is a better option as it is easier to understand and - for more complex situations - way simpler to maintain.

Answer (score 4):

Your first `CASE` expression won't even *compile*, but if we make a small change then it will:

```sql
CASE s.COURSE_SCHEDULED_ID
    WHEN NULL THEN 'false'
    ELSE 'true'
END AS "Is scheduled?"
```

This will be evaluated as this:

```sql
CASE WHEN s.COURSE_SCHEDULED_ID = NULL
     THEN 'false'
     ELSE 'true'
END AS "Is scheduled?"
```

Note very carefully that the `COURSE_SCHEDULED_ID` is being compared to `NULL` using the *equality* operator.  This won't work as expected with `NULL`.  Instead, for `NULL` checks the second verbose version always must be used as it allows `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` checks.

Answer (score 3):

[From the documentaion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96):

> In a simple `CASE` expression, Oracle Database searches for the first `WHEN ... THEN` pair for which *expr* is equal to *comparison_expr* and returns *return_expr*. If none of the `WHEN ... THEN` pairs meet this condition, and an `ELSE` clause exists, then Oracle returns *else_expr*. Otherwise, Oracle returns null.

In you first version you have

```
CASE s.COURSE_SCHEDULED_ID WHEN IS NULL THEN
```

which will throw "ORA-00936: missing expression" because `IS NULL` is a condition, not a value or expression. So then you might think you could do:

```
CASE s.COURSE_SCHEDULED_ID WHEN NULL THEN
```

but that will go to the `else` value because the comparison is "*expr* is equal to *comparison_expr*", and nothing is equal to (or not equal to) null ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Nulls.html#GUID-CDD7FB76-FC1B-492E-8431-871624FADA27)).

In your second version you now have a searched case expression:

> In a searched `CASE` expression, Oracle searches from left to right until it finds an occurrence of *condition* that is true, ...

Now it is expecting a condition (rather than a value or expression), so `s.COURSE_SCHEDULED_ID IS NULL` can be evaluated and is true.

Answer (score 2):

you can check multiple column situations in case when statements.
for example

```
case 
     when s.COURSE_SCHEDULED_ID is null and s.COURSE_ID = 4 
     then true 
     else false 
 end as is_scheduled
```

if you try to show in the 1st way, which value will asign to which columns?
Or you can write different cases:

```
case 
     when s.COURSE_SCHEDULED_ID is null  
     then true 
     when s.COURSE_ID = 4
     then null 
     else false 
 end as is_scheduled
```

Answer (score 2):

just write:

```
CASE
    WHEN s.COURSE_SCHEDULED_ID IS NULL THEN 'false'
    ELSE 'true'
END AS "Is scheduled?"
```

It works anyway.